# How to access a const outside of a method (Discord.js Bot development)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So basically, my bot comes with reaction roles and it works pretty efficiently by using **partials**. One of the checks before assigning the given role, Is to check whether the reaction role is reacted upon the **msgID** that I defined in my code. (This is useful for servers that have a channel like #reaction-roles and there is always 1 message that stays there for people to react with)

That is working fine. However, I was trying to do something new with my bot where I need the msgID to be saved (because the bot repeats the msg over and over to different people), however since the const of msgID is in the method called bot.on(message) I cannot access the const anywhere outside the method. Is there any way to get around this? Perhaps a way to temp store it in a config file?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with discord SDK so this is a more general suggestion.

Think if you really need to use `const` here. I would suggest using `let` and defining it outside of the function like:

```
let msgID


bot.on(message, (message) => {
  msgID = message.id
}) 

// now it's available here
use(msgID)
```

Just keep in mind that `const` will not work here

Answer (score -1):

You can assign obj to `const` variable outside the function and assign value to it inside the function and then you can access it outside the function as well.

Remember, when you assign object to a `const` it is mutable in a sense that you can change its key/values but you cannot assign something else to this variable.

```
    const someObj = {key: null};
    
    function someName() {
      someObj.key = "hello";
    }
    
    console.log(someObj.key);
```

Comment: You cannot change the value of a `const` variable after it is declared.

Comment: Ohh sorry, I totally forgot about that. You can instead use object to do that. I've updated the answer with object method of achieving the same.